# Knockout not sending updated value

Tags: regex, knockout.js

I have a knockout page where I am formatting the input with regex. It makes the input field to a MM/dd/yyyy  format. So if a user inputs "1111" it will change the input vbox to show "01/01/2011" or for "01111" it will show "01/01/2011".

The problem I am facing is that my observable only returning the keystroke entered by user and not the fully formatted item. For example , if user is entering "1111" I get back "1111" instead of the "01/01/2011"

Here is the Html segment

```
<input id="inpEventDt" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="input-small" data-date-blur="true" data-regex="^((\d{0,2})|(\d{1,2}/?\d{0,2})|(\d{1,2}/?\d{1,2}/?\d{0,4}))$"
                       type="text" data-bind="textInput: dateofevent"/>
```

And this is how I have the knockout binding

```
var ViewModel = function (eventdt ) {
var self = this;
self.dateofevent = ko.observable(eventdt);
}

viewModel = new ViewModel("");

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your  text input is bound to `dateofevent` variable. so whenever you change the input value using other than knockout you need to update the knockout variable with new value as well. I suggest using knockout extend or subscribe and then do your regex validation inside subscribe function

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/68/ just an example to prevent user to enter any special characters. You need to do your validation inside validate function and then replace it into target again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to format the text input while the user is typing, because it makes a hard to understand user interface and non intuitive typing experience.

In addition, it's more complicated, because while typing, the input is likely invalid.

Try instead to format your input on some event (blur for example), while validating it on keystroke:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  var regex = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
  this.isValid = ko.observable(false);
  this.date = ko.observable("");
  this.format = function() {
    self.validate(self.date());
    // TODO: something else
  }
  
  this.validate = function(newVal) {
    var matches = newVal.match(regex);
    if (!matches || matches.length != 4) {
      self.isValid(false);
    } else {
      self.isValid(true);
    }
  };
  
  this.date.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    self.validate(newVal);
  });

  this.style = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.isValid() ? "valid" : "invalid";
  }, this);
};

var vm = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input id="inpEventDt" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="input-small" data-date-blur="true" type="text" data-bind="textInput: date, event: { blur: format }, css: style" />
<div data-bind="visible: isValid">OK</div>
```

Comment: I really like your suggestion. One thing that I will lose with your implementation is the user friendliness. Currently my user can type "1111" (only 4 digit) and it will convert to "01/01/2011" on the UI. But with @Tim Yonker, I still have that. This is definitely a great solution.

Comment: I don't get how you can format digits only string to a date. 
For example, what do you expect from string 122011? 2nd of january of year 2011 (1/2/2011), or first of december 2011 (/12/2011) or second of december of year 2011 (12/2/011)? That's why I didn't put the format function and let it to your own

Comment: That was my exact response. But user really liked the fact that they can just input 1111 and it shows 01/01/2011, it was the the regex and  data-date-blur let us do that. After that users can update the string to proper date. But Like I said, I really like the elegance of your solution.

Comment: I have marked yours as a solution. Because it was more useful to my specific problem. I didn't have the solution for the mask, but was able to work around that for now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a read/write computed for this.  Check out the [example 3](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) in the knockout documentation for computed observables.

Also, here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bu6n602v/1/) using moment.js to help with date formatting.

```
var ViewModel = function (eventdt ) {
var self = this;
self.dateofevent = ko.observable(eventdt);

self.formattedDate = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return moment(self.dateofevent()).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        },
        write: function (value) {
            self.dateofevent(moment(value).toDate()); // Write to underlying storage
        }
    });

}

viewModel = new ViewModel(new Date("03/25/2015"));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, since I still have the user friendliness. But on the flip side adding dependency on moment.js.

Comment: I used moment for the simplicity of providing the example fiddle. You can tweak it with your own date parsing code.  The point is that you can use read/write computed observable to handle formatting data types back and forth between text inputs and your model.